# jQuery Mobile - remove the back button, data-nobackbtn property isn't working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, back-button

I have a simple jQueryMobile index.html page. Within that I have two pages using the data-role="page" syntax. The first page is just a splash screen which is auto changed to the second page after a few seconds. The problem is after the page changes from the splash to the homepage, the back button shows (even with data-nobackbtn="true"). If I refresh the second page, the back button is hidden.

I'm using the two page example here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used the following with success:

```
<div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</div>
```

Does it work for you too?

Answer (score 3):

> Within that I have two pages using the
>   data-role="page" syntax.

You should never have a page, WITHIN another page. Pages should each be declared on their own, as shown in that two page example you linked to.

When you said you have the index.html page, and two pages inside it, do you mean index.html is just the actual file name? Or another JQuery Mobile `data-role="page"` element (the latter won't render nice).

Anyways, try `data-backbtn="false"`, as stated above, that should work for you. I never heard of using the `data-nobackbtn="true"`, seems a little redundant anyway, false positives suck.

Comment: `data-nobackbtn="true"` was there upto alpha2, before somebody pointed out that it sounds bad... ;)

Comment: Thanks, data-backbtn="false" works as opposed to data-nobackbtn="true" which is odd, they effectively equate to the same thing based on the language but turn out to be functionally different.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wondering why it doesn't work in newer versions it's because of a breaking change. If you're on jQM 1.1.0 try

```
<div data-role="page" id="login" data-add-back-btn="false">
```

Please not that it's on the page not in the header and the attribute change from data-backbtn to data-add-back-btn

Comment: Thanks! Wondering why my users suddenly had a whole new way to logout

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use

```
   <div data-role="header"  data-nobackbtn="true" >
```

You can check a reference to data-nobackbtn at

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery_android/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have activated the back button in the page definition:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="ptest" data-add-back-btn="true">
```

shoud be

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="ptest">
```